# Server side implementation for RXJS Observables

Tags: node.js, express, rxjs, reactivex

I really liked the way rxjs observables work. I have a application built in  express.js and Angular 7.
Now, I want to implement a live update page in it, when user in on that page, he/she will get live updates from server without sending continuous requests from client side. I know this can be done using socket.io but I want to implement it using rxjs observable. When user will open page, it subscribe to a observable and display latest update.

**My Query:**

I know how it works on client side (angular). But, how I should implement it in expressjs?

Normally, when there is a request from client side, expressjs returns the response and close the request. How to keep connection open and push changes from server (to all users who are on live updates page)?

Also, please let me know, how it will effect server performance? Or is there  any better way to do this?

Comment: **Websocket** is the way to go. Also you may want to add a **PubSub** implementation to enable a client to subscribe to only a certain topics. Even if you managed to implement **rxjs** the way you want you would end up using websockets. Search for **PubSub over websockets** and i'm sure you'll find what you need.

Comment: @Molda Thanks for your reply. For this I will need to use websocket part of rxjs library in my angular app. This will not work with normal Angular HttpClient GET method. As angular HttpClient GET method also returns observable, Is it possible to implement it with normal angular HttpClient module?

Comment: This was done with Angular v2, but I assume it could be updated to current version: https://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/socket.io-with-rxjs-in-angular-2.0